# how to recover from ubuntu 12.04 boot crash

Tags: boot

I've been running Ubuntu for a short time but doing well. Then today, wham, my boot failed & gave me a static screen with a list of 3 major failures like no disk space, no monitor, ..... . I did a reboot and ran the Linux 3.8 Ubuntu recovery utility. It made lots of repairs while i watched the screen flow for several minutes - at the end I got an nice ubuntu brown start screen but then the message : "10.625xxxxx disabled by bios". Then on a flashing screen I got : etc/acpi/power.sh : pm-powersave not found, followed by (OK) and then *"checking battery state". There's no way to stop this flashing screen except shut down. I can't get to a command line cursor. I've seen lots of suggested solutions in this forum today but they all involve typing stuff from the command line like "sudo" followed by various stuff but I can't try them if I can't get a prompt; how do I break this flashing loop to be able to try some of the commands I've seen suggested here in the forum ?  I should add that i'm just a beginner so the terms and syntax are all new to me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At this point and time since you mentioned battery and power messages and you have a loop flashing a message,unplug your coputer and REMOVE the external battery pack if possible.This may clear your memory of any corrupted data (flashing loop) and residual bytes of corrupted memory.Afterwards place your install disk in your CD drive,then turn on.Your system will look at your disk and hopefully pull necessary data to boot up.
Warning Do Not Reinstall at this time.See if your system repairs itself as it boots up with your disk in the drive.At minimum you should be seeing different screens,hopefully with a solution.My experience with Linux/Ubuntu systems,not windows,is it tries to self heal itself as long as it can pull uncorrupted data from an external source.
 Please do not reinstall unless necessary.If you think it through you will find the Linux products are built in a logical manner.The su and sudo are not as scary as they appear.

Comment: I tried removing the battery & couldn't stop the flashing battery message. Also in setup at start of boot I changed settings in bios that relate to power; but nothing works. Tried running with my bootable usb stick that installed Ubuntu & that gave me some tools. I re-ran the linux 3.8 recovery option & it changed stuff but the boot that followed gave same flashing result. I can go into option "Try Ubuntu" and in file system I find "etc/acpi/power.sh : pm-powersave" so maybe its not deleted. Could I get a command line prompt there ? If so what coammand should I use to start repairs ? Thanks